# Splitting this solid string of URL's into a Python List?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, url

I have this solid string of URL's that I get back from a tool I am building but I am unable to figure out how to turn this into a list effectively. Have tried several modules and split parameters but no luck.

```
http://www.nicolasotr.comhttp://www.nicolasrestaurant.com
```

Comment: You should fix the tool to use a proper separator. Or even an exchange format like JSON.

Comment: With weird domains, I can see ambiguous cases coming up. Just delimit them properly from the getgo.

Comment: Did you try `split('http://')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the regex: `(?:http[s]?://)(?:(?!http[s]?://).)*` using the `re` module. This finds the first occurrence of 'http', and matches until it finds the next occurrence of 'http'.

```
import re

urls = "http://www.nicolasotr.comhttp://www.nicolasrestaurant.com"
results = re.findall("(?:http[s]?://)(?:(?!http[s]?://).)*", urls)

>>> results
['http://www.nicolasotr.com', 'http://www.nicolasrestaurant.com']
```

But as others have said, it would be easier to fix your original tool so it outputs separated urls.

Comment: How about `(?:http[s]?://)(?:(?!http[s]?://).)*`, matches `http` and `https`

Comment: I didn't think it was necessary because it matches everything from 'http' (so this includes the 's' in https) until the next 'http'.

Comment: right. but it gets into problem when you have string `http` in domain or subdomain

Answer (score 2):

```
result = "http://www.nicolasotr.comhttp://www.nicolasrestaurant.com"
l = ['http'+x for x in result.split('http') if x]
```

print(l)

```
['http://www.nicolasotr.com', 'http://www.nicolasrestaurant.com']
```

But you should edit your tool to return good values